# Efficient Data Structure To Store Millions of Records

Tags: java, hadoop, memory-management, bigdata

I have an input file that contains millions of records and each record contains again thousands of columns in which each of the column is separated by a delimiter.

Number of records and columns can vary from file to file.

I have a requirement that I have to parse these records and store them in the java object so that it can be further passed to the Drools Framework for the column level validation.

This is how my input data and schema file looks like.

**Input File :**

```
John|Doe|35|10 Floyd St|132|Los Angeles|CA|USA ... and so on 
...
...
Millions records like this
```

**Schema File :**

```
firstName|String|false|20|NA
lastName|String|false|20|NA
age|Integer|false|3|NA
addressLine1|String|false|20|NA
addressLine2|String|false|20|NA
city|String|false|5|NA
state|String|false|10|NA
country|String|false|10|NA
```

I tried to implement this solution with the help of a map and created a Java class containing this map.

```
class GenericRecord {
   Map<String,FieldSpecification> properties; //used HashMap as an implementation
}

class FieldSpecification {
    public String fieldName;
    public String dataType;
    public int length;
    public String value;
    public String format;
}
```

For reach row in the input file I am creating a `Record` Object and using map to store the values of its column. In addition to this I am also storing the metadata about the column in `FieldSpecification` Object like dataType , length  ,format etc.

For few thousands of rows in my input file it worked fine but as soon as number of rows starts increasing , it started blowing off because of the memory issue (as expected). As it is creating millions of map of objects having thousands of keys in it.

I am aware this is not efficient solution is to solve this type of problem.

So my concern is will the in memory based solution work in my scenario or I have to prefer the disk based solution like embedded DB or disk based Maps .

Please advise if is there any other open source Map implementation that I can use.

**Note :** For File Parsing and Data Validation I am using hadoop and it is running on a 40 nodes cluster.

**Here is the flow and implementation of my mapper:**

Receives the value as complete row ,later this row is passed to a Java framework which converts it into a corresponding GenericObject (as mentioned above) and then this object is passed to the drools framework for further validation.

**Mapper Implementation :**

```
public void map(LongWritable key , Text value , Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        //Convert the text value to string i.e line by line comes here
        String record = value.toString();





        // Develop a drools service that will take record as an input 
        // and will validate it on the basis of XL sheet provided
        workingMemory = knowledgeBase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
        DroolsObject recordObject = DroolsServiceImpl.validateByRecord(record, fileMetaData, workingMemory);



        //Check to validate if the processed record
        if(recordObject.isValid) {
            context.getCounter(AppCounter.VALID_RECORD).increment(1);
            mapperOutputKey.set("A");
            mapperOutputValue.set(recordObject.toString());
            context.write(mapperOutputKey,mapperOutputValue);
        }

        else {
            context.getCounter(AppCounter.INVALID_RECORD).increment(1);
            mapperOutputKey.set("R");
            mapperOutputValue.set(recordObject.toStringWithErrors());
            context.write(mapperOutputKey,mapperOutputValue);
        }
}
```

Comment: Use an embedded database to handle this problem. It is too much data (millions of records) unless you have enough RAM to handle it manually.

Comment: Plan for scalability and move to a big data platform (hadoop etc) or large DB

Comment: @C.B. yes we are using Hadoop , and in the mapper implementation everything happens. Updated the question.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza RAM is not a problem upto a level ,but as soon as file size increases it will blow off as it is creating lot of java objects in the memory.

Comment: @saurav *RAM is not a problem upto a level ,but as soon as file size increases it will blow off as it is creating lot of java objects in the memory* in other words, you still don't know if RAM is a problem or not... check that first. If it's not a problem, then do it. If it is a problem, use an embedded database. You should drive your decision around facts rather than suppositions, and you should do proof of concepts to evaluate which alternative to choose for your specific case.

Comment: What happens after you pass the object to Drools? Do you really need to keep the object or are you getting pass/fail per object before you perform the next step?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sorry for not being clear , yes RAM is a problem as it is finite. As at this moment I don't have an exact requirement how big file will be (but at least millions record each) and this will increase in future. So , I think embedded db based solution might work here. Do you have any recommendation for embedded based DB solution ?

Comment: @Baldy After that drools framework set a flag in the GenericRecord whether this record is rejected or passes. On the basis of this flag, record will be written to either accpeted or rejected file. These files are final outcome of our process.

Comment: So instead of keeping each record around why don't you stream process it. Parse a record, check it with Drools and write it out immediately to proper file. You would need minimal memory this way and you could use an Executor queue to optimize execution time. Of course if the records are interdependent, this won't work.

Comment: I am not sure about the stream process , what you mean. Please bear with me. Upto my understanding I am doing the same thing - reading a record , parsing it to a generic record , sending it to drools framework and then writing it to a file. what I am missing here ?

Yes records are independent of each other.

I have added the code for my mapper implementation.

Comment: If the records are all independent,  why do you need to have them all in memory?  Process a single record all the way before you process the next record.  That way you only have one record in memory at a time.

Comment: Yes I don't need them in memory , and processing is happening in the same way. But somehow objects are not getting garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have to save every byte of data that is in the file in memory (except possibly the delimiters), start with looking at the size of the file and comparing it to the size of memory.  If your file is bigger than memory, scratch the whole idea of keeping it in memory.

**If memory is larger than the file**, you have a chance, though you need to carefully examine how this file might grow in the future, what platforms will the program run on, etc.

So **ASSUMING THAT IT FITS**, you can be more efficient with your data structure.  One simple way to save memory would be to scrap the maps and just save each record as a string (as encoded in the file).  An array of strings should have minimal overhead, though you'll want to make sure you're not constantly resizing the original array as you populate it.

Keeping your data structures simple when they get large can save you a lot of memory on overhead.

Also, if the data will easily fit into memory, you may need to do some adjustments to the JVM to allocate enough memory to it (change the heap size [using -Xmx](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html)) to get the JVM large enough.  I hope you're using a 64-bit JVM on a 64-bit platform.

Comment: I can use arrays but i need a relationship to be set between the key and values , so that later Drools framework can use it. I have seen few Map implementation those have the concept of external keys and values are stored in array.

Comment: The bigger question is "Does the data fit in memory?"  You can switch the data structure around if it does.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to keep the data in one (`byte[][]`) table and refer to rows via their number. Then you can use a cursor that reads the corresponding fields on demand:

```
class FieldSpecification {
    private final int row;
    private final byte[][] mem;

    public String fieldName();
    public String dataType();
    public int length();
    public String value();
    public String format();
}
```

The garbage collector should dispose these objects quite easily. You only need to care about their lifecycle.

When the byte-array does not fit into your memory, well, then you are screwed anyway.

You can then implement your map by mapping names to row numbers.